# How to get unique tabId for the browser on the firefox addon

Tags: javascript, tabs, firefox-addon

In my firefox addon, I'm working with tabs follow this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/tabbrowser.

I need to determine unique id (tabId) for each tab. For example,

```
index  | tabId |  tabLink
1      |  11AA |   example1.com
2      |  11BB |   example2.com
3      |  11CC |   example1.com
```

I have a question on the **tabId** field, how to get the unique tabId for each tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i tested it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU79z.png

There is no unique id on the tabs initially. What you have to do is grab the tab, like `var aTab = gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[0]` (this grabs the first tab) then `setAttribute` on it like `aTab.setAttribute('myCustAttr', 'myCustVal123')` then in future you can grab that tab by going `var thatTab = document.querySelector('[myCustAttr="myCustVal123"]')`

Comment: Hi Noitidart, Thank you for your quick reply. It works fine. The best solution for me now.